# How do I iterate over a file?

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have a file that looks like this:

```
[noahc:~/projects/wordsquares] master(+87/-50)* ± cat wordlist/test_word_list.txt
card
apple
joe
bird
card
dart
area
rear
birdbird
after
boat
swim
north
abbe
byes
beep
```

If I open up an irb session, I can do:

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > file = File.open('./wordlist/test_word_list.txt', 'r')
 => #<File:./wordlist/test_word_list.txt>
2.0.0p247 :002 > file.readlines
 => ["card\n", "apple\n", "joe\n", "bird\n", "card\n", "dart\n", "area\n", "rear\n", "birdbird\n", "after\n", "boat\n", "swim\n", "north\n", "abbe\n", "byes\n", "beep \n", "\n"]
```

But, now I have a class called WordSquareGenerator:

```
class WordSquareGenerator
  require 'pry'
  require 'pry-nav'
  require './lib/word_list_builder.rb'

  def initialize(n, file_location)
    @size_of_square = n
    @file = load_file(file_location)
    @word_stem_hash = WordListBuilder.new(n, @file).word_stem_hash
    @word_list = nil
  end

  def word_square_word_list
    binding.pry
    @file.each do |w|
      binding.pry
      @word_list ? break : solve_for_word_list([word])
    end
    binding.pry
  end

  def is_list_valid?(list)
    (0..@size_of_square - 1).each do |n|
      (0..@size_of_square - 2).each do |m|
        return false if list[n][m] != list [m][n]
      end
     end
    @generated_list = list unless @generated_list
  end

  def solve_for_word_list(word_array)
    if word_array.length == 4
      @word_list = word_array
    elsif @word_list
    else
      next_words = @word_stem_hash[word_array.map{|w| w[word_array.length]}.join]
      next_words.each do |word|
        solve_for_word_list(word_array + [word])
      end
    end
  end

private

  def load_file(file_location)
    File.open(file_location, 'r')
  end
end
```

When I run the `word_square_word_list` method and hit the first `binding.pry`, I can do:

```
2.0.0 (#<WordSquareGenerator:0x007ff3f91c16b0>):0 > @file.readlines
=> []
```

and I get an empty array for `readlines`. How can it be that I'm getting two different results doing the same thing, except one is inside that class and the other isn't?

Comment: perhaps try non-private?

Comment: Don't open a file in a method and leave it open for the rest of the program. Get rid of `load_file` and use a `File.open` block that wraps  the call to `WordListBuilder.new`. Also, don't use ternary statements for flow control: `@word_list ? break : solve_for_word_list([word])` should be `break if @word_list` followed by `solve_for_word_list([word])`.

Comment: @theTinMan Why is the ternary operator so bad for flow control?

Comment: @Noah it's unclear because typically it's for returning one of two values. Readable code > Short code

Comment: +1 @Doorknob. Ternary is used (abused) a lot in C and Perl, but it often results in code that hides the logic. Ternary code should be very clean and simple. Reading your example, with a `break` or a method call, obfuscates what you're really doing, which is breaking if a value is set, or calling another method. In reality, using an `if`/`else` would be just as bad. Use a trailing `if` to `break` or fall through to the next method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `WordListBuilder` you are probably reading the file already and when the action gets back to `WordSquareGenerator` the file is already at it's end and there's nothing else to read. First, don't do what you're doing now, that is opening the file since this leaks the file handle (you're not closing it anywhere) and someone else reading the handle is causing your code to fail.

Here's how you could do it:

```
class WordSquareGenerator
  require 'pry'
  require 'pry-nav'
  require './lib/word_list_builder.rb'

  def initialize(n, file_location)
    @size_of_square = n
    @file_location = file_location
    @word_stem_hash = WordListBuilder.new(n, file_location).word_stem_hash
    @word_list = nil
  end

  def word_square_word_list
    binding.pry
    IO.foreach(@file_location) do |word|
      binding.pry
      @word_list ? break : solve_for_word_list([word])
    end
    binding.pry
  end

  def is_list_valid?(list)
    (0..@size_of_square - 1).each do |n|
      (0..@size_of_square - 2).each do |m|
        return false if list[n][m] != list [m][n]
      end
     end
    @generated_list = list unless @generated_list
  end

  def solve_for_word_list(word_array)
    if word_array.length == 4
      @word_list = word_array
    elsif @word_list
    else
      next_words = @word_stem_hash[word_array.map{|w| w[word_array.length]}.join]
      next_words.each do |word|
        solve_for_word_list(word_array + [word])
      end
    end
  end

end
```

And you would also need to update `WordListBuilder` to do the same. This also has the advantage of closing the file handle automatically for you so you don't have to care about closing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this before you read the lines:

```
@file.seek 0
```

You have probably already read the lines, and you have to seek back to the start of the file before you read them again.

Sample IRB session:

```
irb(main):001:0> f = File.new 'test.txt' # already existing file
=> #<File:test.txt>
irb(main):002:0> f.readlines
=> ["this", "is", "a", "test"]
irb(main):003:0> f.readlines
=> []
irb(main):004:0> f.seek 0
=> 0
irb(main):005:0> f.readlines
=> ["this", "is", "a", "test"]
```

You could even make it a method:

```
def readlines
  @file.seek 0
  @file.readlines
end
```

Also, make sure to close your file (`@file.close`)! You should only leave it open for as little time as possible. And you **definitely** should not leave it open for the whole program. If you don't want to worry about that, just store the lines in a variable instead of keeping the file:

```
@lines = File.open(file_location) {|f|
  f.readlines
}
# you could also use the shortcut form
# @lines = File.open(file_location, &:readlines)
```

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares I was assuming that he `@file.close`d somewhere else in the program - I'll edit my answer

Comment: Opening the file in a method, and leaving it open is really bad form, and can take a system to its knees if multiple versions of the app are running and consuming file-handles.

Comment: Just to confirm, I am leaving this open. I thought about closing it, but wasn't sure how since it was being used across the two classes. I'll take a look at this and @theTinMan's recommendation and see what I can do.

Comment: @Noah Do **not** leave it open - that will cause bad things. Just store the information you need from it and close immediately.

Comment: Learn how to use the "block" form for IO and File commands. Ruby makes it really easy to do the right thing.